# Office.Interop - Access MS Word Advanced options

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office

I would like to programatically (C#) change the MS Word Advanced option: "Do not compress images in file" using Office.Interop.

How can I do this.

I have looked through [the MSDN Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.options_members.aspx) but don't see what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but the "Do not compress images in file" option is not accessible via the VBA object model.

Although you could use SendKeys, doing so is not reliable - amongst other things, you can only toggle the setting with SendKeys; you can't test it's current state or set it to a particular state and the keystroke sequence required to access it might change according to which languages a user has installed and which Word version is in use.

Source : http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/MVC/Post/Thread/c87d426e-3571-44a7-85a5-2d7edfa4ce60?category=worddev

Another source with more information (on Powerpoint, but it works exactly the same way as for Word) :
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_powerpoint-mso_other/vba-turn-off-auto-compression/9548f7c0-894d-4e76-acc1-4985df08fd50